# HTML inline images work extremely slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I am working with [zoomy plugin](http://redeyeoperations.com/plugins/zoomy/).

I am generating **first** `data:image/png` **from canvas**,
**second** `data:image/png` from hidden `canvas` which is **50% greater** than first (drawing synchonized):

```
<a href="data:image/png..." class="zoom">
    <img src="data:image/png..." alt="image" />
</a>
```

But in this case zoom works **extremely slow**. I should send each data to server and then obtain them as png files from server? Can I avoid this obvious solution?